# How to calculate the 50% probability multiplier 1.1774 more precisely

Tags: probability

The answer to how many random selections need to be made from a sample size of $n$ before there is a 50% chance of repeating is approximately

$$1.1774\sqrt n$$

I've worked out $1.1774$ experimentally, for example by multiplying $0.999\times0.998\times0.997\times...$ until the result is less than $0.5$ but my method increases in time exponentially, i.e. to increase the precision and work out each extra digit takes 100 times as long as the previous digit. How do you easily and quickly work out the exact value?

What if I wanted to work out a 25% chance or 10% chance of repeating, etc.?

Comment: I'm confused. Let's say there are 5 objects. Let's say we have pulled 2 of them without repeat. Then, the chances we repeat on the next draw is 2/5. Is this what you refer to as the "chance of repeating?"

Comment: This is the birthday problem or collision problem. $\sqrt{\log_e{4}} \approx 1.17741$ so your result is good.  More generally you can use $\sqrt{2\log_e\left(\frac{1}{1-p}\right)}$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Cast_as_a_collision_problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n$ be the size of your bin, you need to find a whole number $m$ that most nearly satisfies

$(1-1/n)(1-2/n)(1-3/n)(...)(1-m/n)=0.5$

Take logarithms:

$\ln(1-1/n)+\ln(1-2/n)+\ln(1-3/n)+...+\ln(1-m/n)=-\ln (2)$

For large $n$ we have $m<<n$, thus we use the Maclaurin series approximation for $\ln(1-x)$.  Then

$(1/n)+(2/n)+(3/n)+...+(m/n)=m(m+1)/2n=\ln(2)$

So $m$ asymptotically approaches $\sqrt{(2n)\ln(2)}$, therefore the limiting value of your coefficient is just $\sqrt{2\ln(2)}$.

For a repeat probability of $p$, replace $0.5$ in the first equation with $1-p$.  Your limiting coefficient is $\sqrt{2\ln(1/(1-p))}$.